# Does the List in SwiftUI reuse cells similar to UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swiftui

I am working on creating a dynamic list using SwiftUI. Does the SwiftUI `List` container reuse the cells similar to `UITableView`?

Comment: Why do you ask? I think `SwiftUI` promises to be performant; whether it reuses views in this specific way is an implementation detail.

Comment: Check the memory graph - it does

Comment: Sorry to chime in, but I just linked to this question because it seems someone else *may* be wondering something close. I was focused on "dynamic" - State (SO interpreted the "at sign" as a user!), array updates, etc. - and it actually may be the question is more concerned with "reusable". I say (at least for now) leave it up. @Matteo_Pacini has been giving quite a few **great** answers about SwiftUI and Combine.. Maybe he could give another one? I'd surely upvote it.

Comment: Check these two answers for more information around this topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56652113/5623035
-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56654877

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> This answer was written for the SwiftUI 1 originally, but it is still correct for the latest SwiftUI version except that it's using `UICollectionView` underneath now.

✅ Yes, `List` is reusing its `ListCoreCellHost`s exactly like the way `UITableView` reuses its `UITableViewCell`s.

Reference:

Investigating memory usage with Xcode shows that, when the number of the items is more than `List` could present at once, it just shows as much as it can and reuses them when they become occluded from the top or bottom of the `list`.

[image]

By tracing a single cell memory address, you can see it is reused over and over.
Another exciting tidbit is that `ListCoreCellHost` uses a hosting view that may refer to `UIKit` internally. (Not known well because it lacks documentation)

[image: Demo]

Comment: By checking the addresses like you suggest, I find that the hosting views and subviews are not reused, only the cell itself.