# What is the equivalent of dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "") in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui

I have created a List using swiftUI

```
List(landmarkData, id: \.id) { landmark in
            LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
}
```

Is swifitUI `List` reuse cell?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the List in SwiftUI reuse cells similar to UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56655421/does-the-list-in-swiftui-reuse-cells-similar-to-uitableview)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using List it "automatically" reuses your "Row".
This is not the case if you are using ScrollView -> ForEach