# SwiftUi : for i in 0... How to solve closure containing control flow statement

Tags: swift, for-loop, swiftui, swiftui-list

I want to display some images that depend on an integer.

Example with '3':

[image]

```
VStack {
     Text(recette.name)
     HStack() {
           Text("Durée 20 min")
             .font(.caption)
             .fontWeight(.light)
           Text("Notes")
             .font(.caption)
             .fontWeight(.light)
           HStack(spacing: -1.0) {
                for 0 in 0...recette.avis{
                      Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                        .padding(.leading)
                        .imageScale(.small)
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                 }
            }
     }
}
```

but the code doesn't compile with this error in for.

> Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with function
> builder 'ViewBuilder'

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/56645647/1187415 ?

Comment: No I already tried and Image cannot be cast to AnyView :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use a `ForEach` so that you can create your stars.

Below is a working example.

```swift
// This is a simple struct to mock the data
struct Recette {
    let name: String = "Test"
    let avis: Int = 3
}

struct ContentView: View {

    let recette = Recette()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(recette.name)
            HStack() {
                Text("Durée 20 min")
                    .font(.caption)
                    .fontWeight(.light)
                Text("Notes")
                    .font(.caption)
                    .fontWeight(.light)
                HStack(spacing: -1.0) {
                    ForEach(0..<recette.avis) {_ in // <- use ForEach() here
                        Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                            .padding(.leading)
                            .imageScale(.small)
                            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what the above code produces:

[image: What code produces]