# How to display a text view in swift UI if the variable isn't nil?

Tags: swift, swiftui

This is basically my code I have:

```
var myString: String?

var body: some View {
  NavigationView {
    if myString != nil {
      CustomView(text: myString ?? "")
    }
  }
}
```

If I try without adding the `?? ""` part, it doesn't work, says `Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String'`. If I add it in as shown above, it seems to work, but why do I need to have a default empty string value if that's never going to be the case? (Since it will only reach that code if myString is not nil) Is there a way I can make this code more cleaner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use optional binding to unwrap the safely optional variable. However simply using that inside `body` will result in a compiler error because not all control flow (including `if let`) is allowed inside the `body` of the view, so you'll need to wrap it in another computed property.

```
struct MyView: View {

    var myString: String?

    var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
        innerView
      }
    }

    var innerView: some View {
        if let myString = myString {
            return AnyView(CustomView(text: myString))
        } else {
            return AnyView(EmptyView())
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can simplify that using `Optional.map`.

```
struct MyView: View {
    var myString: String?

    var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
        myString.map { CustomView(text: $0) }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if let myString = myString {
  CustomView(text: myString)
}
```

This is one of the ways to safely unwrap an optional, but as it was pointed out it won't work inside a view builder block. Instead you can use `map` to keep it simple.

```
var myString: String?

var body: some View {
  NavigationView {
    myString.map { CustomView(text: $0) }
  }
}
```

Comment: And that results in a compiler error `Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with function builder 'ViewBuilder'`. See [How to have a dynamic list of views using SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56645647/how-to-have-a-dynamic-list-of-views-using-swiftui).

Comment: @pizzae no, that piece of code inside your `body` doesn't compile

Comment: @pizzae I updated my answer to work with SwiftUI view builders