# Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate?

Tags: swift, view, swiftui, geocode

I have a view that I'd like to include an if statement with, but when the if statement is added to a ForEach closure, it causes this error to trigger. Are there any workarounds?

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct SearchResults: View {
    @ObservedObject var VModel: ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(self.VModel.searchResults, id: \.self) { result in 
                self.RowText
            }
        }
    }

    private var RowText: some View {
        if result.country != nil { //Cannot access the result variable here?
            return Text("First conditional met!")
        } else {
            return Text("Second conditional met!")
        }
    }

}
```

Side Note: searchResults is an array of type GeocodedPlacemark. VModel is a geocoding class.

Comment: You need to return something if it is nil

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61682953/4667835) answer for how to have a conditional SwiftUI `View` inside the `body` of your `View`. You need to return `EmptyView` in case the condition is false.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I don't think I can return a view, it would mess up the way the view looks...if you could take another look at my code, how could I reference the 'result' variable from the RowText view?

Comment: @nickcoding `EmptyView` results in no visual view being created, hence it will not mess up your UI

Comment: @DávidPásztor Well...I still get the same error if I just return EmptyView(), as seen in Andrew's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use function instead, as below

```
struct SearchResults: View {
    @ObservedObject var VModel: ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(self.VModel.searchResults, id: \.self) { result in
                self.rowText(result: result)
            }
        }
    }

    private func rowText(result: GeocodedPlacemark) -> some View {
        if result.country != nil { //Cannot access the result variable here?
            return Text("First conditional met!")
        } else {
            return Text("Second conditional met!")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Asperi! You're a huge help!